# Build do TypeScript não suporta CommonJS do Node.js

Tags: javascript, typescript

Digamos que eu tenha um módulo `alert.ts`:

```js
export default function alert(message: string): void {
  console.log('Alerta: ' + message)
}
```

Ao realizar o *build* usando o `tsc`, e tentar usar o código gerado pelo Node.js (com JavaScript):

```js
const alert = require('./dist/alert.js')
alert('Hello, World!') // ERRO! `alert` é `undefined`
```

Ele dá erro. O único modo de resolver esse erro é usar o `.default`:

```js
//                                      ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
const alert = require('./dist/alert.js').default
alert('Hello, World!') // OK!
```

**A pergunta é: Como configurar o TypeScript para que ao usar o código gerado com Node.js não haja a necessidade de se usar esse `.default`?**

---

<sup>PS: Já tentei usar as opções `esModuleInterop`, `module` e/ou `moduleResolution`, mas nenhuma das três parece solucionar o problema.</sup>

Comment: Já tentou `import alert from './dist/alert.js';  alert('Hello, World!');` ?

Comment: Sim, e funciona. O problema acontece somente quando uso CommonJS no Node.js (JavaScript).

Comment: Eu pensei no seguinte o interpretador não pode estar entendendo `function alert(message: string): void {  alert(message); }` como uma função recursiva? Se você fizer `function alert(message: string): void {  Window.alert(message); }` qual seria o resultado?

Comment: Na verdade o problema está na fase de compilação do TypeScript. Só não sei como arrumar isso. O TS não consegue usar gerar um _build_ que também seja compatível com o CommonJS do Node.JS. Aliás, o `alert` realmente foi um exemplo errado, já que não existe no Node... Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Amigo, transpile/compile o typescript com o webpack!

Comment: @LuizFelipe você está utilizando o Typescript com o backend (nodejs) é isso? Poste também mais informações sobre as suas configurações do typescript e como está utilizando no mesmo para compilar.

Comment: Tenta utilizar esta flag na hora de chamar o tsc, ex: tsc --allowSyntheticDefaultImports
documentaçao: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Você está utilizando o módulo `ts-node`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apesar de não sentir que seja o mais ideal, consegui resolver **atribuindo** o valor exportado à palavra-chave `export`:

```js
export = function alert(message: string) {
  console.log(message);
}
```

Penso que uma forma mais "*correta*" de se fazer isso seria usando ferramentas como `webpack` ou `rollup`. Porém, o que fiz acima serviu para as minhas necessidades.

[Aqui](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb-keyval/blob/ea7d50752fd6a92eda003df021eb1976a0a35ef4/rollup.config.js) é possível consultar um arquivo de configuração do `rollup` que também poderia resolver o meu problema. Não cheguei a pesquisar um exemplo para o `webpack`.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se você já tentou isso, mas e se retirar o *default* do módulo que vc criou? Exemplo:

```
export function alert(message: string): void {
  console.log('Alerta: ' + message)
}
```

Outra coisa, você está chamando o módulo como `alert.js`, mas está criando como `alert.ts`.

Espero ter ajudado!